# Let A⊆R be a set. Prove that A is bounded if and only if there is some M∈R such that M>0 and that |x|≤M for all x∈A.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, proof-writing, supremum-and-infimum

I proved the above problem as follows but received feedback that I'm not certain I understand.  Can someone help me determine where I went wrong in the proof?

> Let A⊆R be a set.  Suppose M∈R where M>0 and |x|≤M for all x∈A.  Thus -M≤x≤M for all x∈A.  It is reasonable to conclude that A is bounded with an upper bound M and a lower bound -M.
>
> Let A be bounded.  It follows that there exists a lower bound a∈R and an upper bound b∈R.  Thus |a|≤x≤|b| for all x∈A.
>
> Let |a|≤|b|.  Then -|b|≤-|a| and -|b|≤x≤|b| for all x∈A.  It follows that -(|b|+1)0 and |x|≤M for all x∈A.
>
> Let |b|<|a|.  Then -|a|≤x<|a| for all x∈A.  It follows that -(|a|+1)0 and |x|≤M for all x∈A.

I thought I did a pretty good job but my professor thought my two cases should be different. She also suggested that I missed a step, that I need to assume that |a|≤|b| means that x ≤-a =|a|≤|b| but I'm really not following that suggestion at all.

Comment: maybe your professor wants a topological argument of a bounded set?

Comment: What is your definition of a set being bounded? There are generally 2 (equivalent) definitons for subsets of real numbers:   1 that there exists an upper and lower bound number (Or a single M like you have here),    or that the set is a subset a ball of a certain radius (in the reals, such a ball is a symmetric interval)

Comment: I am using the definition that there exists and upper and lower bound number.

Answer (score 1):

> Thus $|a|≤x≤|b|$ for all $x∈A$.

This is incorrect; you put absolute values where they don't belong. The definition of upper and lower bounds tells you that $a\le x\le b $ for all $x \in A$.

> It follows that -(|b|+1)0

This looks like a broken formula.

> Let $|a|≤|b|$

This is a misuse of "let". It is meant to signal the reader that some assignment has been made, like "let $c=4$". Here, $a$ and $b$ are already introduced, you can't apply "let" to them as if they were fresh variables. It's better to write:
"There are two cases. Case 1: $|a|\le |b|$. Case 2: $|a|>|b|$."

One   problem with the two final paragraphs is that you never said what $M$ is. If you want to convince the reader that $M$ exists, it helps to spell out what it is: $M=|b|$ in the first case, for example.

---

(You could shorten the proof with $M=\max(|a|,|b|)$, unifying the cases.)

Comment: Okay... I think I follow your suggestions.  I'll work on it a bit more taking this into consideration.  Appreciate your help.